# Check iRedMail version installed

Tags: centos, postfix-mta, iredmail

I have an iRedMail installation in a Centos 6.6 VM, I'm trying to create email accounts through the database: the procedure change if you have 0.9.6 version or minor as you can read [here](https://docs.iredmail.org/sql.create.mail.user.html).

Because it works with the minor's version process I know that's my case but I still don't know which version of iRedMail I have.

Answer (score 0):

Someone said [here](https://forum.iredmail.org/topic2964-iredmail-support-determine-version-and-upgrade.html) that you can check it with

```
more /etc/iredmail-release
```

In fact, in the docs, for [every version update](https://docs.iredmail.org/iredmail.releases.html) you have [that instruction](https://docs.iredmail.org/upgrade.iredmail.0.9.6-0.9.7.html#general-all-backends-should-apply-these-steps).

Comment: Hey, do you know where `iRedMail-X.X.X/tools/`  directory is located based in the docs? Besides, I was trying to run the SQL Commands (as the docs refer) inside MySQL but I couldn't execute `SOURCE user.sql` sentence successfuly. Do you have any references to solve this problem? Thanks.